# GSuite Google mail reports through API

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I would like to access the GSuite reports to fetch the email logs periodically and be able to parse them locally to find anomalies . The only way I can do that right now is going through the Reports tab.

Is there any way I can accomplish this through an API ?

Thanks.

Comment: Try to check the [Reports API: Users Usage Report](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/manage-usage-users) if it can help you in your case. The user usage report returns G Suite service activities across your account's users. These reports can be customized and filtered for specific usage information. You can retrieve all user usage activities here and retrieve a specific user's usage activities. Just read the documentation to know more about it.